# What are good resources for Chinese calligraphy?

Tags: writing, resources, handwriting, calligraphy

Pen writing and brush writing is also welcome.
If possible, I hope you can give your evaluate for these resourses.
I have heard 灵飞经 is a good copybook. Are there something close to that?

Comment: I'm not sure what did you mean 'resources'. A specific copybook? A specific style guide? An calligraphy style introduction?

Answer (score 1):

The best resource is a good teacher who would teach you right and good calligraphy. A book may be convenient, but it would not tell you where you're wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this so hopefully it's not too late. I'm creating a series of Chinese calligraphy tutorials in English and the most recent upload is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aRQGx4sMdQ&t=115s. Hope it's helpful if you're interested.